# How to replace rownames of a list of dataframes with values from a list of character strings in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, mapply, r-rownames

Let `l` be a list of two dataframes and `n` a list of character strings, wherein `l` and `n` both have two elements. Also, let the number of rows of each dataframe in `l` be equal to the length of the vector of character strings in `n`.

```
l <- list(data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3)),
          data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(1,2,3,4)))
n <- list(c('a', 'b', 'c'), c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
```

Suppose we want to replace the `rownames` of the two dataframes in `l` with the character strings in `n`. The desired result would be:

```
> l
[[1]]
  x y
a 1 1
b 2 2
c 3 3

[[2]]
  x y
a 1 1
b 2 2
c 3 3
d 4 4
```

I believe one could exploit `mapply` for this task, but I cannot figure how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rownames<-` and `Map` as follows

```
Map(`rownames<-`, l, n)
# or mapply(`rownames<-`, x = l, value = n, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Result

```
#[[1]]
#  x y
#a 1 1
#b 2 2
#c 3 3
#
#[[2]]
#  x y
#a 1 1
#b 2 2
#c 3 3
#d 4 4
```

`rownames<-` sets the rownames of `x` to `value`. In your case `x` is a single dataframe in `l`, and `value` is a vector from `n`. This function is applied "to the first elements of each ... argument, the second elements, the third elements, and so on.", from `?mapply`.

And "`Map` is a simple wrapper to `mapply` which does not attempt to simplify the result", see `?Map`